# Reference from UITableViewCell to parent UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to access the owning `UITableView` from within a `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Store a `weak` reference to the tableView in the cell, which you'd set in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of your table's dataSource.

This is better than relying on `self.superview` to always be exactly the tableView is fragile. Who knows how Apple might re-organize the view hierarchy of `UITableView` in the future.

Comment: To be safe, you might want to add a '[self.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]' check, just in case the view hierarchy changes in the future.

Comment: actually, this seems a bit of hacking it, because what if some table design have some containers first, and they contain the cells, in which case, `cell.superview` may not be the table, so it is making an assumption of the UITableView implementation here

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer Did you not read my edit made a long time ago? I suggest putting your own `weak` reference to the tableview when the cell is created/displayed. That should still work.

Comment: I read it, and I think it is important that since evil superview calls were part of the original answer, that you don't simply delete the edits. The weak reference is the correct way and anyone that walks the view hierarchy is asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, they did change this with IOS 7 :)

Comment: You can traverse subviews without relying on any particular view hierarchy, as suggested in the `Category` below. This guarantees it will work in future versions. That way you don't have to scatter references all over your code and increase object coupling.

Comment: This answer is bad design, not sure why it has so many votes. Probably the better answer below arrived later, but do take the time to read it anyway, there is a very interesting discussion in the comments.

Comment: @JamesDonald What’s bad about keeping a weak reference to the tableView?

Comment: @jbrennan it introduces tight-coupling and also violates the Law of Demeter in terms of OO design, part of the reason why Apple doesn't have a "parentTable" property in the first place. DTs explains it nicely in the comments of his answer below.

Comment: @JamesDonald Apple didn't add a "parentTableView" method either so it's not very clear what motivated Apple either way.  In a lot of cases no reference is needed to the table so adding a reference would chew up bytes.  Adding a reference can cause problems since people tend to reference the table in the cell.  Configuring the cell can then inadvertantly make calls to the table when the cell is reused.  Given the simplicity of the code I go with a weak reference.  Better using a little bit of memory than chewing up someone's battery constantly going up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a nicer way to do it, which does not rely on any particular UITableView hierarchy. It will work with any future iOS version, provided that `UITableView` does not change classname altogether. Not only this is extremely unlikely, but if it does happen you will have to retouch your code anyway.

Just import the category below and get your reference with `[myCell parentTableView]`

```
@implementation UIView (FindUITableView)

-(UITableView *) parentTableView {
    // iterate up the view hierarchy to find the table containing this cell/view
    UIView *aView = self.superview;
    while(aView != nil) {
        if([aView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            return (UITableView *)aView;
        }
        aView = aView.superview;
    }
    return nil; // this view is not within a tableView
}

@end
```

```
// To use it, just import the category and invoke it like so:
UITableView *myTable = [myTableCell parentTableView];

// It can also be used from any subview within a cell, from example
// if you have a UILabel within your cell, you can also do:
UITableView *myTable = [myCellLabel parentTableView];

// NOTE:
// If you invoke this on a cell that is not part of a UITableView yet
// (i.e., on a cell that you just created with [[MyCell alloc] init]),
// then you will obviously get nil in return. You need to invoke this on cells/subviews
// that are already part of a UITableView.
```

**UPDATE**
There is some discussion in the comments about whether keeping a weak reference is a better approach. It depends on your circumstances. Traversing the view hierarchy has some small runtime penalty as you are looping until the target UIView is identified. How deep are your views? On the other hand, keeping a reference on every cell has a minimal memory penalty (a weak reference is a pointer after all), and generally adding object relationships where they are not needed is considered a bad OO design practice for many reasons, and should be avoided (see details in the comments below).

More importantly, keeping table references inside cells adds code complexity and can lead to errors, because `UITableViewCells` are reusable. It is no coincidence that `UIKit` does not include a `cell.parentTable` property. If you define your own you must add code to manage it, and if you fail to do so effectively you can introduce memory leaks (i.e., cells live past the lifetime of their table).

Because typically you'll be using the category above when a user interacts with a cell (execute for a single cell), and not when laying-out the table in `[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` (execute for all visible cells), the runtime cost should be insignificant.

Comment: @mattcurtis If you find yourself walking subviews you should ask yourself, why? And this bad idea is best illustrated by the iOS 7 change to UITableViewCell that will make this always return nil. A weak reference is the way to go if you need to get a hold of the tableview from the cell.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer Well, stating it that way would have been much more helpful than your original comment. Thank you for the explanation, by the way.

Comment: @mattcurtis Point taken. I have removed the unhelpful comment.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer No, this still works fine in iOS7 and it will keep working in future iOS releases. Many of our apps in the app store still use this code without a problem, just put it in the right place as suggested in the code comments. Storing references all over the place does not promote a clean design and many design books suggest that it is avoided.

Comment: @DTs sorry, but walking the view hierarchy is always bad business. Certainly as a method of finding your superview.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer if you would like readers to consider your opinion, it would be helpful to justify it. Stating an idea as dogma without illustrating the problem, does not help anyone evaluate it or learn from it. The code above is generic and does not brake, and I have provided comments to show the pros and cons to the weak reference approach. If you have something more to contribute, please do elaborate. So far what we have seen is that you didn't fully understand how the code above works, since you claimed erroneously that it does not work in iOS7.

Comment: @DTs your dogma, it works. My dogma is, that code smells. When you roll the view hierarchy it says you haven't designed your program well and it can be summarized as a general violation of the Law of Demeter. Your view should not grope through the views trying to find a matching UIWhateverView. There is nothing anti-OO about having a series of references to subviews, if you have too many that is more likely a structural issue and rolling the view hierarchy is an end run around the structural problem. So I'm not advocating for a weak reference, I'm advocating against your solution.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer good OO design and the Law of Demeter in particular, states that "units should have only limited knowledge about other units and do so only when absolutely necessary". This is to promote loose unit coupling and reusability. Keeping references to subviews is in fact the violation of LoD, not traversing the views in a view-hierarchy agnostic manner. The latter promotes loose coupling and good OO reusable design, and in fact well respects the LoD. Perhaps what you do not like is traversing subviews while relying on a fixed hard-coded hierarchy, which is not the case here.

Comment: @DTs that is certainly one way to interpret it. However, I think you missed the point. Your view knows that somewhere, not an immediate neighbor, lives a table view. You call it loosely coupled because it doesn't have an ivar holding a reference to the table. I don't. A view that lives several layers below the table view should exist without knowing what exists above. I agree keeping a reference to a view n-layers down is also a bad idea. So this brings me back to my point, if you're walking the subviews groping for a tableview then you haven't structured this well.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer a `UITableViewCell` is constrained by design of `UIKit` to live underneath a `UITableView`. Looking for **an** instance of that `UITableView` in a `UIView hierarchy-agnostic` manner introduces no additional relationships. The `UITableViewCell` is then said to be `loosely coupled` in Software Eng. In contrast, maintaining a reference to a **particular** `UITableView` instance inside a `UITableViewCell`, is considered tight-coupling because a direct relationship is introduced. It is not by accident that there is no `UITableViewCell.parentTable` property offered in UIKit.

Comment: @DTs a UITableViewCell is by its very nature a subcomponent of a specific UITableView. Your point about the lack of a parentTable component is important. Your table view cell should not need to know that there is a table and UIKit encourages good design by omitting a parentTable reference. Introducing an ivar or walking the hierarchy are materially the same and should be avoided.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer if you think that the 2 solutions discussed here are "materially the same", I recommend studying Apple's "Programming with Objective-C", which is an excellent introductory guide to this language. It should help you clear up the difference between these 2 directly opposing solutions discussed here. By the way, given that the original problem that the OP posted can only be solved with one of the two competing approaches discussed here, you last comment seems to suggests that the OP should not solve this common and simple problem, and give up instead. This makes no sense.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer this started as a good discussion but at this point it's clear that your point has been well-defeated, your last few comments don't make any sense and they seem to only serve an "I want to win this" purpose. +1 to DTs for responding courteously all this time for the benefit of us all, I actually did learn a lot from this argument. Perhaps next time you should try to be less provocative, your opening comments were indeed quite annoying instead of constructive. And as it turned out, you were flat out wrong.

Answer (score 15):

*Xcode 7 beta, Swift 2.0*

This works fine for me, in my opinion it has nothing to do with the hierarchy or whatever. I had no trouble with this approach so far. I've used this for many async callbacks (ex. when an API request is done).

*TableViewCell class*

```
class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    var updateCallback : ((updateList: Bool)-> Void)? //add this extra var

    @IBAction func btnDelete_Click(sender: AnyObject) {
        let localStorage = LocalStorage()
        if let description = lblItemDescription.text
        {
            //I delete it here, but could be done at other class as well.
            localStorage.DeleteItem(description) 
        }
        updateCallback?(updateList : true)

    }
}
```

*Inside table view class that implements the DataSource and Delegate*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: ItemCell = self.ItemTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as! ItemCell!
    cell.updateCallback = UpdateCallback //add this extra line
    cell.lblItemDescription?.text = self.SomeList[indexPath.row].Description
    return cell
}

func UpdateCallback(updateTable : Bool) //add this extra method
{
    licensePlatesList = localStorage.LoadNotificationPlates()
    LicenseTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Ofcourse you can put any variable in the `updateCallback` and change it's function in the `tableView` accordingly.

Someone might want to tell me if it is save to use though, just to be sure.

Comment: I have implemented this code for two different cells. In the first cell, i have updateCallback, for the second cell I have updateCallback2. I know 100% all my methods and variables are named correctly, however, updateCallback2 is nil (updateCallback is fine). What could be causing it to be nil?

Comment: Are you setting it? `cell.updateCallback2 = UpdateCallback2`?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If I may add, you can spare checking updateCallback is nil by using optional chaining like this: `updateCallback?(updateList : true)`. If the callback is set the call will happen.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add a reference back to the UITableView when you construct the table view cell.

However, almost certainly what you really want is a reference to your UITableViewController... that requires the same thing, set it as a delegate of the cell when you build the cell and hand it to the table view.

An alternate approach if you are wiring up actions is to build the cells in IB, with the table view controller as the files owner - then wire up buttons in the cell to actions in the table view controller.  When you load the cell xib with loadNibNamed, pass in the view controller as the owner and the button actions will be wired back to the table view controller.

Answer (score 4):

If you have custom classes for your UITableViewCells, you can add an id type variable in your cell's header, and synthesize the variable. After you set the variable when you load the cell, you are free to do what you please with the tableview or any other higher view without much hassle or overhead.

cell.h

```
 // interface
 id root;

 // propery 
 @property (nonatomic, retain) id root;
```

cell.m

> @synthesize root;

tableviewcontroller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // blah blah, traditional cell declaration
  // but before return cell;
  cell.root = tableView;
}
```

Now you can call any of the tableview's methods from within your cell using the root variable. (e.g., [root reloadData]);

Ah, takes me back to the good old days of flash programming.

Comment: You don't really want it to be retained though. The tableview usually owns the cell.
This would be better 
 `@property (nonatomic, assign) id root;`

Answer (score 2):

The two methods in other answers are: (A) store a reference to the table, or (B) walk up the superviews.

I'd always use something like (A) for model objects and (B) for table cells.

#### Cells

If you are dealing with a UITableViewCell, then AFAIK you must either have the UITableView at hand (say you are in a table delegate method), or are dealing with a visible cell that is in the view hierarchy. Otherwise, you may well be doing something wrong (please note the "may well").

Cells are liberally reused and if you happen to have one that is not visible then the only real reason that cell exists is because of iOS UITableView performance optimization (a slower iOS version would have released and hopefully dealloc'd the cell when it moved off screen) or because you have a specific reference to it.
I guess this is probably the reason that table cells are not endowed with a tableView instance method.

So (B) gives the right result for all iOS's so far, and all future ones until they radically change how views work.

Though in order to avoid writing generalizable code over and over, I'd use this:

```
+ (id)enclosingViewOfView:(UIView *)view withClass:(Class)returnKindOfClass {
  while (view&&![view isKindOfClass:returnKindOfClass]) view=view.superview;
  return(view);
}
```

and a convenience method:

```
+ (UITableView *)tableForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
  return([self enclosingViewOfView:cell.superview withClass:UITableView.class]);
}
```

(or categories if you like)

BTW, if you are concerned about the effect of a loop with 20 or so iterations of that size on your app performance,.. don't.

#### Models

If you are talking about the model object that is displayed in the cell, then definitely that model could/should know about its parent model, which may be used to find, or trigger changes in, the table(s) that the cell's model might be displayed in.
This is like (A), but less brittle with future iOS updates (eg one day they might make the UITableViewCell reuse cache exist per reuseidentifier, rather than per reuseidentifier per tableview, on that day all the implementations that use the weak reference method will break).

Th **model** method would be used for changes to the data displayed in the cell (i.e. model changes) since changes will propagate wherever the model is displayed (eg. some other UIViewController somewhere else in the app, logging, ...)

The **cell** method would be used for tableview actions, which would likely always be a bad idea if the cell isn't even a subview of a table (though it's your code, go nuts).

Either way, use a unit test rather than assuming that seemingly cleaner code just works when they update iOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *) self.superview.superview;
UITableViewController *vc = (UITableViewController *) tv.dataSource;
```