# Get reference of tableView through a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is possible to get the reference of the tableView that the UITableViewCell has been added?
I mean, if I have an UITableViewCell and I want to know who is your tableView, can I find out?
Does exist some property or something?

Thank's in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need this?

You might consider reworking your code to avoid the need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, UITableViewCell inherits from UIView. This thread [Reference from UITableViewCell to parent UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110482/reference-from-uitableviewcell-to-parent-uitableview) suggests using self.superview