# How detect indexPath on click button at row?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I have this `UItableView`:

[image]

I would like to increment/decrement the concrete `UIProgressView` at row, when I clicked on minus/plus and than also reload, whole `UITableView`, because all rows are interdependent. I don't how detect on which row was pressed the minus/plus `UIButton`. I tried to use rowDidSelect, but it didn't work. Could you please advise me please?

**EDITED**

I have a class for `UITableCell` (ActivityCell - class) and class for `UITableViewController` (lessonActivityTVC - class). At class of Cell I have `IBOutlets`.

```
ActivityCell.h
@interface ActivityCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *studentNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
```

In ActivityCell.m I have nothing new. I had here a IBActions for buttons, but I moved the actions into `lessonActivity.m` because, when I press any button I need reload the `UITableView` and I didnt know how do it in `ActivityCell.m`. My code of lessonActivityTVC.m is here:

```
@implementation tchLessonActivityTVC
#define debug 1

- (IBAction)incrementActivity:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"increment");
}
- (IBAction)decrementActivity:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"decrement");
}

-(void)fetchData{
    CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]cdh];
    SchoolClass *schoolClass = (SchoolClass*)[cdh.context existingObjectWithID:[IDsManager getClassID] error:nil];
    Lesson *lesson = (Lesson*)[cdh.context existingObjectWithID:[IDsManager getLessonID] error:nil];

    if (lesson.activities.count == 0) {
        for (Student *student in schoolClass.students) {
            Activity *activity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Activity" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
            activity.student = student;
            activity.lesson = lesson;
            [lesson addActivitiesObject:activity];
            [student addActivitiesObject:activity];
        }
    }
    self.activities = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[lesson.activities allObjects]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self fetchData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.activities.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(debug == 1){
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'",self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    static NSString *cellIndetifier = @"Activity Cell";
    ActivityCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndetifier
                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Activity *activity = [self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.studentNameLabel.text = activity.student.name;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 5.0f);
    cell.progressView.transform = transform;

    cell.progressView.progress = 0.32f;        
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected index is %d",indexPath.row);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` has a delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and you get the indexPath.row from there. Don't forget to set your class as a `UITableViewDelegate` by adding `<UITableViewDelegate>` on the end of `@interface` line and setting

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

in code, or do it in Interface Builder. If you are on `UITableViewController`, you get this for free.

**Edit:**

Here is the delegate pattern example:

tableviewcell h

```
@protocol TableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)requestToReloadTableViewFromCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;

@end

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <TableViewCellDelegate> cellDelegate;

@end
```

tableviewcell m

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.cellDelegate requestToReloadTableViewFromCell:self];
}
```

tableviewcontroller m

```
@interface TableViewController () <TableViewCellDelegate>

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)requestToReloadTableViewFromCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell] row]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.cellDelegate = self;
    cell.dateLabel.text = [[NSDate date] description];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yep. I know. I wrote "I tried to use rowDidSelect, but it didn't work.", because it works, when I click next to a button (plus/minus). When I click ON THE BUTTON, no row is selected.

Comment: Because the touch event is consumed by the button. If you use prototype cell and UITableViewCell subclass, I would make an IBOutlet from the button to the subclass and you will then have a reference to the sender, which is a cell that has an index.

Comment: Well, you have a reference in IBAction as well, so it pretty much depends on how and where you act on the touch. Show us the code.

Comment: I would then bring the IBAction back to the cell subclass and use delegate patern to inform the tableView which cell's button was selected and ask for changes and table reload.

Comment: Or perhaps, you can avoid creating delegate callback from cell and can use this solution to have reference to parents tableview in cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110482/reference-from-uitableviewcell-to-parent-uitableview

Comment: I brough the IBAction to the cell subclass. Could you please a little bit advise with the "delegate pater to inform...."? I have never use it.

Comment: Use the solution from the link, this is easier. I am editing the answer to show that.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tag with these buttons programatically in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Tag should be different for each button (you can use some formula, for example tag will be equal to row no). in this way when button will be pressed you will check tag first and can know which button is pressed at which row.

Comment: Yep. I know. I wrote "I tried to use rowDidSelect, but it didn't work.", because it works, when I click next to a button (plus/minus). When I click ON THE BUTTON, no row is selected.