# How can I identify a table row in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made a prototype cell and I have data from a database to load into the cells in a table.
Each cell has a label and 3 buttons just like this:

[image]

If I click on a button for example "Meets Standard", how can I identify in which row I tapped the button?

So for example when I press the "Meets Standard" button at a given row I'd like to change the background color of that row to red. How can I do it?

I have a CustomCell.swift class where I configure the prototype cell and a TableView.swift class where I configure the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try control dragging the button to your CustomCell.swift class and typing a name and selecting "Action" on the popup menu.  Then, inside the generated method, you can call `self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` or perform any other operations that you'd like.

Edit:

Here's what I think you should do to change the height:

Make a boolean in your cell class called "expanded" or something.  Then, go into your table view class and implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.  In that method, retrieve the cell and check if it's expanded, and if so, return a larger height.  Now, to make it reload, you will need to store a reference to the table view in each cell, as it says here: [Reference from UITableViewCell to parent UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110482/reference-from-uitableviewcell-to-parent-uitableview)

In that clicked method you already made, where the background is set to red, you will need to call:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

where tableview is the weak reference you already stored.  Also, in that method, you need to add `self.expanded = true` of course.

Edit 2:

You know what, maybe it's easier to just do this:

```
weak var _tableView: UITableView!
```

...

```
func tableView() -> UITableView! {
    if _tableView != nil {
        return _tableView
    }

    var view = self.superview
    while view != nil && !(view?.isKindOfClass(UITableView))! {
        view = view?.superview
    }

    self._tableView = view as! UITableView
    return _tableView
}
```

Comment: This works, perfect. What if I'd like to change the height?

Comment: "you will need to store a reference to the table view in each cell, as it says here" Can you explain this part please? It seems to that they use Objective-C and I don't really understand it.

Comment: Haha just put them in the CustomCell.swift class. The `weak var` statement goes at the very top, above all the methods, and the tableView method goes with all the other methods. @nethuszar

Comment: Okay :) It says something like " Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'isKindOfClass...' "

Comment: Where does it say that? Is that a compiler error or does it crash or something? I just tested it and don't see any errors @nethuszar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117630/discussion-between-nethuszar-and-john-farkerson).